How to use Matplotlib Renderer class in combination with custom OpenAI gym env
I'm currently working with the code of someone else to replicate some of their work (https://github.com/romanlee6/multi_LLM_comm). This code contains a custom OpenAI gym environment. I've managed to get the code running, but I want to show a live visualization of the task while it's running. The gym env contains a file called 'render.py' which contains an instance of the matplotlib Renderer class. I think I should somehow call this in dragonExp.py or dragonTextEnv.py, but I have no clue how.
Do any of you know example projects that do this, or can you help me achieve what I want?
Thank you!
